# Split dataframe and apply function to 2 different rows in R

Tags: r, split

I'm trying to apply a `mi.meld` to a list of 144 data frames in order to combine sets of estimates and their standard errors. As `Amelia` doesn't work with lists, I unnested it into a large data frame, where each 2 rows correspond to the original data frame. Below is a snapshot of my data (288 rows).

I want to find a quick way not to repeat the command 144 times  `mi.meld(data,q=data[1,],data[2,])`, and `mi.meld (data,q=data[3,],data[4,])`, and 142 more times...

So, in the first case `q` should be a vector of values of the first row and so on...

Thanks, Lucas

```
   nn        V1         V2         V3
ARE.1  1 357.85116 356.859011 359.432494
ARE.2  1   8.54784   7.450074   9.711469
ARE.3  2 503.99528 506.120967 507.520785
ARE.4  2  14.52657  12.129299  14.469123
AUS.1  3 421.60845 423.302610 425.196122
AUS.2  3  29.31331  27.230948  28.605672
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about splitting a frame by rows, why did you add the [tag:plyr] and [tag:imputation] tags? They seem unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

```r
rownum <- seq_len(nrow(mtcars))
split(rownum, (rownum-1) %/% 2)[1:3]
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2
# $`1`
# [1] 3 4
# $`2`
# [1] 5 6
L <- lapply(split(rownum, (rownum-1) %/% 2), function(rn) mtcars[rn,])[1:3]
L
# $`0`
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# $`1`
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# $`2`
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Once you have a `list` where each element is a 2-row subset of the original frame, you can likely do something like

```r
lapply(L, function(x) ...)
```

where `...` is whatever you expect the your call to be.

A little shorter:

```r
ret <- lapply(split(rownum, (rownum-1) %/% 2), function(rows) {
  if (length(rows) > 1) {
    mi.meld(mtcars[rn[1],], mtcars[rn[2],])
  }
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something like this would help :

```
library(Amelia)
row_index <- seq(1, nrow(data), 2)
row_index <- row_index[row_index < nrow(data)]

result <- lapply(row_index, function(x) mi.meld(data[x,], data[x + 1,]))
```

Comment: Careful ... if there are an odd number of rows, this'll produce an all-`NA` row. (Granted, this is likely not an issue if the data is well-known going into this.)

Comment: @r2evans Will it? I thought this runs the same irrespective of whether the number of rows are odd or even.

Comment: Okay, I misread your code. Then different: this does rows 1:2, then 2:3, then 3:4 ... the OP was 1:2 then 3:4 then 5:6. I think.

Comment: You are right about that. Corrected the answer. Thanks.